# how to recall swipe detector in onResume() method?

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I have two method one is shake-Listener and second is swipe Detector. 
With onResume() Only shake-Listener are working good.

I don't know how to recall Swipe Detector in onResume().

my swipe-detector code.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
return true;    
}
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void onLeftSwipe() {

     finish();  
    overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.left_in,R.anim.left_out);
 }

private void onRightSwipe() {
  // Do something
    finish();   
    overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_out , R.anim.right_in);
}
    // Private class for gestures


public class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
  // Swipe properties, you can change it to make the swipe 
  // longer or shorter and speed
  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
  private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
  private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                       float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    try {
      float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
      float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

      if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
        return false;

      // Left swipe
      if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) >     SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
    shake_or_swipe.this.onLeftSwipe();

  // Right swipe
  } else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) >     SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
    shake_or_swipe.this.onRightSwipe();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("Shake Activity", "Error on gestures");
}
return false;
  }
}
```

Any one can tell me that how can I resume swipe detector with onresume()..?

OnResume() method

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
super.onResume();

Log.d("overheardword", "onResume Invoked");
//swipedetector.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY,View.OnTouchListener);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: add your on resume code also?

Comment: I have edit onResume() method..

Comment: How can I add Swipe detector in OnResume() method.? can you tell me..??